# Multiple target=_blank window.opens at a time buffering output

Tags: javascript, window, buffering

I have a program in perl and javascript.   When the user confirms the action a new window is opened.  I don't want to name it since I want a new window each time so I use the _blank naming convention.  It works.  This window then gets output from another process.    While it is getting input (it can take a while) any subsequent window.open calls with _blank will not work.   BUT - if I refresh the parent webpage, then I can open a new window and I can keep doing this same refresh and have lots of open windows loading the buffered input from other processes at the same time, which is what I want.  I just don't want the user to have to do the refresh.  I can also wait until the buffering is done, then I can run the confirm again and another window opens (no refresh needed).    So I'm assuming this problem has something to do with the buffering.

Here is the code:

```
$form_action = "<form name=\"myform\" action=\"all.pl\" method=get onsubmit='return confirmAction();window.open(\"about:blank\",\"\",\"menubar=false, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=false\");' target=\"_blank\"> <input type=hidden name=login value=$login>";
```

Some websites suggest a unique name each time, but this code only gets run once if I do not refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer.   I can add a javascript refresh to the onsubmit event.  It works. It is a location.reload(true) call.